# "nosplit stack overflow" when building Go project?

Tags: go

I did a spring cleaning in my code by splitting it up in more Go packages, mainly to help reusability (each "building block" in its own package).

After fixing the import errors, I discovered that my program suddenly won't build. Running "go build" returns a *nosplit stack overflow* error.

> ## robot main.init: nosplit stack overflow
>
> ```
>     120     guaranteed after split check in main.init
>     112     on entry to robot/web.init
>     104     on entry to robot/controller.init
>     96      on entry to robot/slam.init
>     88      on entry to robot/slam/hector.init
>     80      on entry to hectormapping/map/mapimages.init
>     72      on entry to hectormapping/map/maprep.init
>     64      on entry to hectormapping/map/mapproccontainer.init
>     56      on entry to hectormapping/scanmatcher.init
>     48      on entry to hectormapping/map/gridmap/occbase.init
>     40      on entry to hectormapping/map/gridmap/base.init
>     32      on entry to hectormapping/map/gridmap.init
>     24      on entry to github.com/skelterjohn/go%2ematrix.init
>     16      on entry to math.init
>     8       on entry to math.init┬À1
>     0       on entry to runtime.panicindex
>     -8      on entry to runtime.morestack00
> ```
>
> ## runtime.main: nosplit stack overflow
>
> ```
>     120     guaranteed after split check in runtime.main
>     128     after runtime.main uses -8
>     120     on entry to main.init
>     112     on entry to robot/web.init
>     104     on entry to robot/controller.init
>     96      on entry to robot/slam.init
>     88      on entry to robot/slam/hector.init
>     80      on entry to hectormapping/map/mapimages.init
>     72      on entry to hectormapping/map/maprep.init
>     64      on entry to hectormapping/map/mapproccontainer.init
>     56      on entry to hectormapping/scanmatcher.init
>     48      on entry to hectormapping/map/gridmap/occbase.init
>     40      on entry to hectormapping/map/gridmap/base.init
>     32      on entry to hectormapping/map/gridmap.init
>     24      on entry to github.com/skelterjohn/go%2ematrix.init
>     16      on entry to math.init
>     8       on entry to math.init┬À1
>     0       on entry to runtime.panicindex
>     -8      on entry to runtime.morestack00
> ```

Does anyone know what this is about? I can't find much documentation as to what might be causing it, except that for some cases this is [a bug that supposedly is fixed](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3085).

Some of the code was split into a new folder in the "src" folder, so that the file structure is now:

```
src/robot/main.go (main() lives here)
src/robot/(...) (application-specific packages)
src/hectormapping/(...) (stand-alone package used in "robot")
```

I am using Go 1.0.3 on Windows 7 (x64).

Comment: Did you try with go tip rather than stable?

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood No, is there an easy way to do this in Windows?

Comment: I don't know of an `msi` for go tip, but you can [build from source](http://golang.org/doc/install/source) if you have a compiler easily enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be the same as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-dev/RhsK9ljAklM) which was said to be fixed in tip. The corresponding fix can be reviewed [here](https://codereview.appspot.com/6855088/).

To summarize the problem as I am seeing it:
[Split stacking](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks) is used for growing stacks instead of the conventional fixed memory area. This has the benefit that more threads can be spawned, as only the needed stack memory is actually reserved. The problem here seems to be that the linker marks functions that don't use memory on the split stack accidentally as 'nosplit' because it doesn't find the split stack prologue. This leads to the linker calculating a wrong stack limit, which in turn lets the linker think there's no space and throws the error message at you.

Sadly, the only way of getting the tip version is to compile it by yourself. As Nick Craig-Wood already mentioned, you can find the instructions [here](http://golang.org/doc/install/source). If you really really can't upgrade, you could try to work around this by allocation some arbitrary local variable in your `init` functions. But this is very messy of course.

Comment: You and Nick Craig-Wood are right, the problem is fixed in the tip version! Installing the tip version didn't turn out to be a big problem, just a `hg clone` and running a `.bat` file.

I did run into another problem, but it is likely related to `cgo` and unrelated to the topic of this question.

Thanks for the answer, and also for the alternative work-around, which might come in handy!